# Does jQuery On Work For Future Events

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the *old* days, we used to use jQuery's `.live()` (http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind to future events, if content was reloaded via AJAX, for example.

Since `.live()` is now deprecated (and removed), jQuery suggest the use of `.on()` ( http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead. They do not state that it works for future events. **Incidentally**, it's not working on elements reloaded via AJAX.

My question; does `.on()` work, or is it supposed to work for *future* events, in the way that `.live()` does/used to?

I'm calling `.on()` as follows:

```
$j('#header-cart').on('click', '.skip-link-close', function(e) {
    ... // change the world
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling `on`?

Comment: yes it does. without an example we wont be able to help you further

Comment: Do you mean that you create the header-card item via ajax, but you want to start the listener before it loads?

Comment: @Kinnza, yes. Although it is already loaded, but it gets updated.

Comment: So why not start the listener after? Also you have some answers below that might work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, it works in a very similar way to live with the difference that you do not bind the event to a *future* element but to an underlying static element. `.on` makes use of event propagation / bubbling.

As an example

```
<div class="static-element">
    <div>
        <!-- Content inserted from ajax call below -->
        <p class="volatile-element">Example content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

With `.on` bind to the static element and target the volatile element.

```
$(".static-element").on("click", ".volatile-element", function(event) { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach the event `.on()` in different way when replaced with `.live()`

For live

```
$('#ele_id').live('click', function() { 
  // event code
});
```

For on:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ele_id', function() { 
  //  event code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you are calling `$.on` in a wrong way! Yes, it is the replacement for `.live()`, which was awesome.

Have a static element: `#static-div` and the dynamic content, say `.dynamic-link`, inside that `<div>`. You need to call `.on()` this way:

```
$("#static-div").on("click", ".dynamic-link", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or, if you are not at all sure, you can do this way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dynamic-link", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```